# Python - How to convert a List into an Adjacency List for graphs structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph

My problem is that I can't convert a graph constructed through a list into a graph constructed as a dictionary, which must act as an adjacency list.

I have already constructed a random generated graph by randomly adding to each edge: start node (string), end node (string), weight (int).
But now I would need to convert it to a graph like this (a dictionary) that represent an adjacency list:

```
example_graph = {
        'A': {'B': 2, 'C': 3},
        'B': {'A': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 4},
        'C': {'A': 3, 'B': 1, 'F': 5},
        'D': {'B': 1, 'E': 1},
        'E': {'B': 4, 'D': 1, 'F': 1},
        'F': {'C': 5, 'E': 1, 'G': 1},
        'G': {'F': 1},
    }
```

These graphs must be the same, that's why i need to convert the first one.
So what I did then is to put those three initial values (start node, end node, weight) into a list called graphConvert like this:

```
        while i < graph.numberOfNodes():
        graphConvert.insert(i, list(zip(graph.edges[i].node1.printSingleNode(), graph.edges[i].node2.printSingleNode(), [graph.edges[i].weight])))

        deleteIntegers.append(graph.edges[i].weight)
        i += 1
    deleteIntegers = list(set(deleteIntegers))
```

That's an example of the result: [[('C', 'B', 4)], [('A', 'D', 2)], [('D', 'C', 3)], [('A', 'C', 4)]]

Then i added this code to convert the list into a dictionary:

```
adj_list = {}
    for edge_list in graphConvert:
        for edge in edge_list:
            for vertex in edge:
                adj_list.setdefault(vertex, set()).update((set(edge) - {vertex}))

    for i in range(deleteIntegers.__len__()):
        adj_list.__delitem__(deleteIntegers[i])
```

That's the result: {'C': {'B', 3, 4, 'D', 'A'}, 'B': {'C', 4}, 'A': {'C', 2, 'D', 4}, 'D': {3, 'C', 2, 'A'}}

I was hoping to obtain something like this: {'C': {'B': 4, 'D': 3, 'A': 4}, 'B': {'C': 4}, 'A': {'D': 2, 'C': 4}, etc. etc.

But as you can see the results are incorrect, and I can't figure out how I can solve this problem. For example, I don't understand how I can stop the for loop before it gets to the node's weight and print it without sense, however then I would have to insert it afterwards to correctly display the distance between the starting and ending node.
But that is just one of the things I am not understanding and what is wrong with the program.
I've been banging my head about it for a while now and I'm not getting the hang of it, maybe I need a rest!
I haven't been using python that long, so I still have a lot to learn.
Thank you so much in advance to anyone who answers me!

Comment: "These graphs must be the same, that's why i need to convert the first one" -- what does "first one" refer to? All I see is a vague verbal description of "a graph constructed through a list". What is the format of such a list?

Comment: Run your code on a smaller ( say 3 nodes ) graph - then you will see better what is going on.

Comment: EDITED: That sentence means that i can't create another graph from scratch, but i have to convert the first one that i already created named "graph" into this adjacency list. So my problem is to convert "graphConvert" that is a list containing all my edges that came from the graph named "graph" into a graph that is a dictionary, the one named "adj_list". I'm sorry if I can't explain myself well, but I'm not English.

Comment: You're setting the values to a `set()` instead of a `dictionary`

Comment: The function setdefault() is the closest method that i found that let me create the adjency list as I need it. I think i'm confusing the set data type with the dictionary, but in this case seems to almost works for my need. Or maybe i'm wrong using it and there's another method that suits my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph_to_convert = [[('C', 'B', 4)], [('A', 'D', 2)], [('D', 'C', 3)], [('A', 'C', 4)]]
g = defaultdict(dict)

for edge in graph_to_convert:
    a,b,w = edge[0]
    g[a][b] = w

print(g)

#defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'C': {'B': 4}, 'A': {'D': 2, 'C': 4}, 'D': {'C': 3}})
```

If you aren't happy with having a defaultdict as the final product, you can add the line `g = dict(g)` to cast the result to a straight `dict`.

Comment: Thank you so much IT WORKED finally!! And if i may ask... what's the difference between deafultdict and dict ?

Comment: @CuloAtomico Using a defaultdict allows you to write `g[a][b] = w` without having to first check if the inner dictionary `d[a]` exists. If it doesn't yet exist, a dictionary will be automatically created.